# Cache URL of Image I added via FTP

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, image, image-upload

Is it possible to get the cache url of an image you just uploaded via ftp? if yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The images/cache URL is generated when the images is accessed via browser.